# Multiply value of 2 indexes in foreach loop

Tags: php

I want to multiply the values of 2 indexes in my foreach loop.

E.G.

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
    $result=$item['foo']*$item['bar'];
}
```

Then I want to return the result of the sum of all the $result within the function. For example,there are 2 rows of results in the foreach loop, I want to sum them up and return $sum. Anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: How about: $result += $item['foo']*$item['bar'];

Comment: http://3v4l.org/so5V3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($items as $item)
{
   $result=$item['foo']*$item['bar'];
   $sum += $result;
}

return $sum;
```

Is this what you want. It will add all $result in $sum and return $sum if this code is in a function.

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to solve it before seeing your reply